# Intellij Run Configuration Spring Boot vs Maven Issues

Tags: java, maven, jsp, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm trying to run my Spring Boot project with Intellij IDEA.
This project is of type Spring MVC, meaning that it has JSP files in path `main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`.

My `application.properties` has these settings:

```
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

When I'm running the project in Intellij as a "Spring Boot Run Configuration" the server can't identify the path of the JSP files. This is the message i get:

[image]
z

If I run the project with "Maven Run Configuration" with the command `spring-boot:run` everything is working fine.

I have no idea why this is happening. The code and settings of the project are the same with each Run Configuration.

You can try this project (not my project) to understand what I mean https://github.com/mariuszs/spring-boot-web-jsp-example.

My project is behiving the same.
I should note that when the project is running with Spring Boot Run Configuration I do see in the console that the controllers are mapped correctly.

```
2017-06-28 08:29:13.906  INFO 10308 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        : Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]

2017-06-28 08:29:13.835  INFO 10308 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.intuit.mintbills.controllers.generic.LoginController.getLoginPage()
```

Comment: why the `webapp` is in the `main` package?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be there? https://github.com/mariuszs/spring-boot-web-jsp-example/tree/master/src/main   https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/src/main. the second example is of Spring Boot formal examples

Comment: I think you might need to mark the `webapp` folder as "Resources" in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with IntelliJ and Spring boot. You should check the following things:

#### Web facet

Make sure that you have the **Web** facet enabled. The sample project does not have a `web.xml` file, and due to that, IntelliJ doesn't pick up `src/main/webapp`. You can add a dummy `web.xml` file to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` and reimport the project, or you can manually add the web facet and configure it properly. If the web facet is configured correctly, you should see a blue circle in the webapp folder.

An example of a dummy `web.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

And this is the "blue dot" in the `src/main/webapp` folder:

[image: project structure]

#### Provided dependencies

Another issue with IntelliJ is that the provided dependencies are not properly picked up. You can usually fix this by opening **Project Structure...**, by opening **Modules** and selecting the **Dependencies** tab. In here you can override the scopes of your dependencies, so in your case I would suggest configuring both `tomcat-embed-jasper` and `ecj` to **Compile**.

[image: dependency configuration]

I haven't done this recently, but it's possible that this will be overriden everytime you change your `pom.xml`. In that case I would suggest overriding the `<scope>` in you `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you're planning to deploy your application on a web container (eg. an external Tomcat), you may want to work with profiles, otherwise this could lead to conflicts since these dependencies are provided by the web containe.

#### JSP limitations

It's also recommended to change you packaging to WAR, since there are a few [known limitations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) by using JSPs with JAR files. Quoting the documentation:

> When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some limitations in the JSP support.
>
> - With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work, and will also be deployable to a standard container (not limited to, but including Tomcat). An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat.
> - With Jetty it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work, and will also be deployable to any standard container.
> - Undertow does not support JSPs.
> - Creating a custom error.jsp page won’t override the default view for error handling, custom error pages should be used instead.

Comment: This worked in the sample project that I mention in the question, but for some reason in my own project it doesn't work... I'm not sure why.

In my project I'm trying to run the configuration in a specific module and not the entire project.

Comment: You said to make the webapp with a blue dot icon, but from intellij documentations that means that this folder is a package but is it?

When I configure the Web Facets I get an icon of a folder with a globe on it. I have 2015 version of Intellij.

Comment: @OmriYaHoo could be due to different versions. A package does indeed have a dot as well, but I notice that this dot is smaller than the dot on the webapp folder and packages have a black dot now, so I guess this is a change between IntelliJ 2015 and IntelliJ 2017.

Comment: Tried with version 2017. We now have the blue dot on webapp folder and everything seems to be configured correctly. Sadly I still can't map the JSP when running a project as a Spring Boot Run Configuration. Maven Run Configuration working good, have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Well, then you have a different problem than the example code you referred to. Can't help with that since I can't reproduce it. Create a [mcve].

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem by setting the working directory to $MODULE_DIR$ in the run configuration.

Comment: Yes! The problem is that IntelliJ doesn't include JSP files etc to the classpath automatically

Comment: or $MODULE_DIR$ works for me too, if not $MODULE_DIR$

Comment: @John - can you please correct the typo? I see no difference in the variable name.

Comment: @Muzammil sorry my bad. I meant to say $ContentRoot$.