# intellij Spring boot There are too many redirects

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have one Spring Boot project in my company.

It works if you run this with eclipse or java -jar.

Too many redirects when running in IntelliJ. occurs.

Infinite redirection from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to login page.

Is there a workaround without modifying the source code?

Comment: Can you show your code and the error? Which url gives the error? Have you checked similar posts, e.g. the https://stackoverflow.com/a/39310646/2000323 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/40495409/2000323

Comment: Thank you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794588/intellij-run-configuration-spring-boot-vs-maven-issues
I saw this and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with maven:run, not java run.
There is an issue where jsp cannot be executed as run due to a problem in IntelliJ.
Therefore, I ran it with maven:run of Plugins. If there is a better way, please share.